# Как вытащить ссылки из всех страниц сайта? Как сделать пагинацию в селениуме?

Tags: python, selenium, pagination

Пишу парсер с помощью пайтона и селениума. Не могу понять что не так я делаю? Идет только до второй странице (А там у меня 344 страниц!) и потом ошибка:
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
(Session info: chrome=89.0.4389.128)

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.imobiliare.ro/vanzare-apartamente/bucuresti')
time.sleep(5)

coockies = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="modalCookies"]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/a').click()                  

box = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="container-lista-rezultate"]/div[3]')

links = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('img-block')

list_of_links = []
condition = True
while condition:
    for link in links:
        list_of_links.append(link.get_property('href'))
        print(list_of_links)
    try:
        next_page = driver.find_element_by_class_name('butonpaginare').click()
        time.sleep(2)
    except:
        condition=False
```

Comment: страница не успевает прогружаться

Comment: Спасибо! Это я и предполагал. Только вот не могу решить проблему... И это очень печально

Answer (score 0):

```
def wait(xpath) -> bool:
    """
    Метод для ожидания загрузки элемента на странице
    также можно использовать указав любой тег
    в кодировке xpath к примеру wait('//a')
    таким образом браузер будет ждать появление тегов <a>

    :param xpath: xpath элемента для ожидания
    :return bool: True
    """
    for _ in range(60):
        elements = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)
        if elements is not []:
            return True
        else:
            time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Спасибо. Попробую